# Running an exhaustive search across combinations of columns in a Pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe, optimization

I am running an exhaustive search across combinations of columns in a Pandas df.  There is no objective function and hence, no optimization.  Just an exhaustive series of df filterings.

I have set of standardized files.  For each, I build a df structured as:

Customer        'A', 'B', 'C', ... 'K', 'Metric1', 'Metric2', 'Metric3'

Columns A-K are features over which I wish to filter the df.  Using itertools, I create all unique combinations of 5 from these cols.

Columns 'Metric1' - 'Metric3' contains other values for which I want to calculate means once the df has been filtered.

The df has an index 'Customer'.

```
# Features
featureList =  ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K']
numInputs = 5

# Build a list of unique parameter combinations (list of tuples)
AllParms = []
AllParms = list(itertools.combinations(featureList, numInputs))

# Create a list of integers to identify the iteration, i1, i2, i3, etc.
iteration = list(range(1, len(AllParms) + 1))

# Loop thru files
for file in filenames:

    # Read data file.
    df = pd.read_csv(file, index_col='Customer', header=0)

    # Loop thru parameter sets
    for j in range(len(AllParms)):

        ''' 
        Get a unique parameter set (an element from the list of tuples).
        Parse tuple into variables to create df booleans 
        Get parms from 'AllParms' and iteration number from 'iteration'
        '''         

        parmToIterate = AllParms[j]

            parmn = 'i' + str(iteration[j])
            parmA = parmToIterate[0]
            parmB = parmToIterate[1]
            parmC = parmToIterate[2]
            parmD = parmToIterate[3]
            parmE = parmToIterate[4]
            concatStr = parmA + '_' + parmB + '_' + parmC + '_' + parmD + '_' + parmE


            ''' Filter df '''
            # Method 1
            df[parmn] = (
            (df[parmA] > 0) &
            (df[parmB] > 0) &
            (df[parmC] > 0) &
            (df[parmD] > 0) &
            (df[parmE] > 0)).astype(str)
            df2 = df.loc[df[parmn].isin(['True'])]

            # Method 2
            Cond1 = df[parmA] > 0
            Cond2 = df[parmB] > 0
            Cond3 = df[parmC] > 0
            Cond4 = df[parmD] > 0
            Cond5 = df[parmE] > 0
            AllCond = Cond1 & Cond2 & Cond3 & Cond4 & Cond5
            df2 = df[AllCond]


            ''' Calc Metrics for Filtered Rows'''
            Metric1_mean = round(df2['Metric1'].mean(),3)
            Metric2_mean = round(df2['Metric2'].mean(),3)
            Metric3_mean = round(df2['Metric3'].mean(),3)

            ''' Join metrics for all parm sets and unique parm string '''
```

Questions:

1. The code above works fine but I have read many negative comments about dynamically creating df columns.  What is wrong with creating df[ element from a list or tuple ] = something?  What would be an alternative when looping thru sets of cols?
2. Method 2 is 6.7x faster than method 1.  I understand method 1 is a pure row-wise operation but is not method 2 as well?

Answer (score 0):

For 1. you can try:

```
conditions = (df[list_of_columns]>0).all(1)
```

2. problem is that method 1 converts booleans to string and work on comparing strings, which are generally slower.